# Mysql how to design my settings table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building a simple cms in php and mysql that will be used for inhouse projects. Now I'm kind of stuck on the the way I should design my mysql table for the settings. There will be multiple projects with different settings in the database

What would be the right way to design?

Option 1:

1 table for every different project, named "prefix_settings" where prefix will be a unique code for the project. The settings will be stored in the table like:

```
____________________________________
| ID |   Option  |       Value     |
____________________________________
| 1  | site_name |       Foo       |
____________________________________
| 2  | Tagline   |    my tagline   |
____________________________________
| 3  |    URL    |  ww.website.com |
```

Option 2:

1 table for all projects. The prefix will be a column in the table to see which settings are from which project.

```
__________________________________________________________________
| ID |   projectprefix  |  name   |      site      |    Tagline  |
__________________________________________________________________
| ID |     Project_1    |  foo    |  www.site.com  |    blabla   |
__________________________________________________________________
| ID |     project_2    |  bar    |  www.site.com  |    blabla   |
```

Option 2:

1 table for each different project, name of the table would be "prefix_settings". Only the options are the column names instead of values

```
_______________________________________________
| ID |  name   |      site      |    Tagline  |
_______________________________________________
| ID |  foo    |  www.site.com  |    blabla   |
_______________________________________________
```

Note that my example only has 3/4 different settings, but the finished project could have over 20/30 different settings

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is fine for 1 project. But you want to have more, so I would recommend you to create a table named "projects". So you can store the different projects in in. To save the options modify your "options" table and give it another column for an foreign key from "options" to "projects"

Example:
Project Table

```
__________________________
|project_id|project_name |
__________________________
|     1    |   Project1  |
|     2    |   Project2  |
__________________________
```

Option Table

```
___________________________________________________
| fk_project_id |  option_name   |  option_value  |
___________________________________________________
|        1      |       url      |  www.site.com  |
___________________________________________________
```

Comment: Yeah. so like option 2. where collum projectprefix contains the forgein key?

Comment: Would be a good option to, but if you take a look to the database normalization, it is not recommend. I edit my answer that you can see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would depend on a few factors. Do all projects use the same settings?
In case they do I'd go for option 2.

If they only share a few settings and the rest depends on the project I'd got for something like this:

```
// table: projects
_______________________________________________
| ID  |  name   |      site      |    Tagline  |
_______________________________________________
| 123 |  foo    |   www.site.com |    blabla   |
_______________________________________________

// Table: settings
_______________________________________________
| ID |  project_id | option    | value        |
_______________________________________________
| 1 |  123        | something | with_a_value  |
_______________________________________________
```

Comment: Yeah im not sure about that one yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's no right or wrong way to do this as long as you abide by the basic rules of relational database design. I would suggest the following:

```
   Project
+-----------+
| id | name | -- maybe add more project meta-data here like e.g. site or similar
+-----------+    

           Settings
+--------------------------------+
| id | project_id | name | value |
+--------------------------------+
```

Here the name and value would correspond to configuration key-value pairs.

You probably already have a table which is similar to the project table described above (or you should if you're managing many projects), so this would make more sense for me.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing im still thinking about is if all projects use the same options. But thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Merijndk the idea of the above is that you can specify different options for different projects by having different `name -> value` pairs. If your projects will have the same options then a different structure may be better suited.

Comment: Yeah I agree on that